# JMeter 3: Clearing DNS Cache with DNS Cache Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, dns, jmeter

I'm doing performance tests against an AWS ELB, and previously with the older version, I used the DNS Cache Manager in order to get this working. (so that it properly hits every instance under the load balancer, instead of just picking one and re-using that IP). That was great.

But now I'm using JMeter 3 with the same test plan - but I'm noticing using Wireshark that DNS Cache Manager is not causing the same behaviour for the LB, as it is again picking one instance's IP and reusing it.

I've tried moving it around under the thread group, unticking "clear cache each iteration", changing DNS Servers list, and even using the system DNS resolver. The logs show that it does start-up against each thread in the test. I'm using HTTPClient4 for the HTTP Request implementation.

Am I missing something in the new version that should be on in order for this to work again? Or could it actually be bugged?

Comment: Did you ask the question elsewhere or open a ticket about that? What was the outcome?